# To define a custom model name in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Can anyone suggest me how I can define a custom model name. When I tried to generate a model with name 3AForm it's raising a error.

```
rails g model 3A_Form date_of_investigation:date date_of_transcription:date by:string                    investigator:string type_of_investigative_activity:text results_of_investigation:text
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not going to work, `3A_Form` is not a valid class name in Ruby. Perhaps you should try `rails g model Form3A ...` instead. If you need to connect your model to an existing table with a strange name then you can use `table_name` in your class:

```
class Form3A < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'your_weird_table_name'
    #...
end
```